# Using Glide to load ImageView but still have a visual reference in the layout xml

Tags: android, android-glide

I've been able to greatly improve my app's performance using Glide, but it means I've had to remove the srcCompat line from the ImageView in the layout xml.

However, this makes designing much harder, because now I can't reference anything in my Design tab when arranging my xml.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Working without being able to see the image in the xml is extremely inconvenient.

***Example:***

**Before using Glide:**

in my activity_main.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightNarrowGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/leftNarrowGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/money_coins" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/example"
    style="@style/BigRedButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="EXAMPLE"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rightNarrowGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leftNarrowGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image" />
```

and it looks like this in the [Design tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfJWO.png).

**After using Glide:**

Now I load the image in my MainActivity.java with

```
ImageView mainImage = findViewById(R.id.image);
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.money_coins).into(mainImage);
```

and I've removed this line:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/money_coins"
```

from my activity_main.xml, so I'm left with this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightNarrowGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/leftNarrowGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/example"
    style="@style/BigRedButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="EXAMPLE"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rightNarrowGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leftNarrowGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image" />
```

And now my Design tab looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Nxc.png).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to see your image on preview. Well I guess you could set `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/money_coins"`, which basically sets a "placeholder" image for preview. But by doing this you would need to update drawable on two places.

Dunno exactly if you're also changing your image, but for static image use, directly assigning src in layout should be fine performance wise. Unless your drawable image is like huge. If that is the case you should properly resize it or even better, use vector drawable resource. I'm guessing glide downsamples image for you, hence making it load faster.